# can only concatenate str (not “int”) to strについて

Tags: python, python3

フォルダ内の.logというファイルを順次読み込み、.txtというファイルに書き出す処理を行っていますが、
out.write(line.split() + "\n")でcan only concatenate str (not “int”) to strというエラーが
発生してしまいます。

調べてみると、「数値を文字列にする」ということですが、下記コードの場合、どの様に、文字列型に変換すればよいのでしょうか？

```
import glob

# カレントディレクトリのフィル名取得
files = glob.glob('*.log')

# 取得したファイルを1ファイルずつ読み込み
for file in files:

    # ファイル名の拡張子の前だけ取り出し
    newfilename = file.split(".")[0]
   

    with open(newfilename + '.txt','w') as out:

        # 取得したファイルを開き1行読み込み
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
            line = f.readline()

            # ファイルを最終行まで読み込み
            while line:
                
                # 数字で始まるときだけ、.txtへ書き込み
                if line[0] >= '0' and line[0] <= '9':
                    out.write(",".join(line.split()) + "\n") # ここでエラー発生!!
                line = f.readline()
```

カレントディレクトリ内にある.logファイル
test1.log

```
ID   name     price
1    リンゴ　100
NG   -      -
2    みかん　150
```

test2.log

```
ID   name     price
3    ごはん　100
4    みそしる　150
NG   -        -
5    ニンジン 10
```

テキスト書き出し後↓
test1.txt

```
ID,name,price
1,リンゴ,100
2,みかん,150
```

test2.txt

```
ID,name,price
3,ごはん,100
4,みそし,150
5,ニンジン,10
```

Comment: `line.split()` ではなくて `line.strip()` なのではないでしょうか？ その場合は `out.write(line)` で充分ではないかと。

Comment: 一部、質問内容に不足がありました。.txtへ書き出す時は、コンマ区切りとして書き出したいです。なので、line.split()で分割しました。

Comment: 了解です。`line.split()` だけの場合はリストになりますので、コンマ区切りにする場合は `','.join(...)` を使うとよいかと思います。

Comment: 有難うございました。目的の処理はできました。本コードで、can only concatenate str (not “int”) to strの解決方法については、分かっていないのですが、目的の処理はできたため、本件は、解決済みとさせていただきます。

Comment: 解決済みなので蛇足になりますが、手元の環境(`Python 3.10.6`)で編集前のコードを実行した際には `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list` と表示されていました。

Comment: 細かい話ですが，列名も書き出す仕様なら「if 文の条件に `line[:3] == 'ID '` を`or`で加える」などが必要と思います。